# Why this js code's RSA encrypted result is different from java's RSA standard code?

Tags: java, javascript, encryption, cryptography, rsa

Here is javascript code named `Barrett`. It can do RSA encryption and I put it into code snippet:

```js
/*
 * RSA, a suite of routines for performing RSA public-key computations in JavaScript.
 * Copyright 1998-2005 David Shapiro.
 * Dave Shapiro
 * dave@ohdave.com 
 * changed by Fuchun, 2010-05-06
 * fcrpg2005@gmail.com
 */

(function($w) {

if(typeof $w.RSAUtils === 'undefined')
        var RSAUtils = $w.RSAUtils = {};

var biRadixBase = 2;
var biRadixBits = 16;
var bitsPerDigit = biRadixBits;
var biRadix = 1 << 16; // = 2^16 = 65536
var biHalfRadix = biRadix >>> 1;
var biRadixSquared = biRadix * biRadix;
var maxDigitVal = biRadix - 1;
var maxInteger = 9999999999999998;

//maxDigits:
//Change this to accommodate your largest number size. Use setMaxDigits()
//to change it!
//
//In general, if you're working with numbers of size N bits, you'll need 2*N
//bits of storage. Each digit holds 16 bits. So, a 1024-bit key will need
//
//1024 * 2 / 16 = 128 digits of storage.
//
var maxDigits;
var ZERO_ARRAY;
var bigZero, bigOne;

var BigInt = $w.BigInt = function(flag) {
        if (typeof flag == "boolean" && flag == true) {
                this.digits = null;
        } else {
                this.digits = ZERO_ARRAY.slice(0);
        }
        this.isNeg = false;
};

RSAUtils.setMaxDigits = function(value) {
        maxDigits = value;
        ZERO_ARRAY = new Array(maxDigits);
        for (var iza = 0; iza < ZERO_ARRAY.length; iza++) ZERO_ARRAY[iza] = 0;
        bigZero = new BigInt();
        bigOne = new BigInt();
        bigOne.digits[0] = 1;
};
RSAUtils.setMaxDigits(20);

//The maximum number of digits in base 10 you can convert to an
//integer without JavaScript throwing up on you.
var dpl10 = 15;

RSAUtils.biFromNumber = function(i) {
        var result = new BigInt();
        result.isNeg = i < 0;
        i = Math.abs(i);
        var j = 0;
        while (i > 0) {
                result.digits[j++] = i & maxDigitVal;
                i = Math.floor(i / biRadix);
        }
        return result;
};

//lr10 = 10 ^ dpl10
var lr10 = RSAUtils.biFromNumber(1000000000000000);

RSAUtils.biFromDecimal = function(s) {
        var isNeg = s.charAt(0) == '-';
        var i = isNeg ? 1 : 0;
        var result;
        // Skip leading zeros.
        while (i < s.length && s.charAt(i) == '0') ++i;
        if (i == s.length) {
                result = new BigInt();
        }
        else {
                var digitCount = s.length - i;
                var fgl = digitCount % dpl10;
                if (fgl == 0) fgl = dpl10;
                result = RSAUtils.biFromNumber(Number(s.substr(i, fgl)));
                i += fgl;
                while (i < s.length) {
                        result = RSAUtils.biAdd(RSAUtils.biMultiply(result, lr10),
                                        RSAUtils.biFromNumber(Number(s.substr(i, dpl10))));
                        i += dpl10;
                }
                result.isNeg = isNeg;
        }
        return result;
};

RSAUtils.biCopy = function(bi) {
        var result = new BigInt(true);
        result.digits = bi.digits.slice(0);
        result.isNeg = bi.isNeg;
        return result;
};

RSAUtils.reverseStr = function(s) {
        var result = "";
        for (var i = s.length - 1; i > -1; --i) {
                result += s.charAt(i);
        }
        return result;
};

var hexatrigesimalToChar = [
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j',
        'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't',
        'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'
];

RSAUtils.biToString = function(x, radix) { // 2 <= radix <= 36
        var b = new BigInt();
        b.digits[0] = radix;
        var qr = RSAUtils.biDivideModulo(x, b);
        var result = hexatrigesimalToChar[qr[1].digits[0]];
        while (RSAUtils.biCompare(qr[0], bigZero) == 1) {
                qr = RSAUtils.biDivideModulo(qr[0], b);
                digit = qr[1].digits[0];
                result += hexatrigesimalToChar[qr[1].digits[0]];
        }
        return (x.isNeg ? "-" : "") + RSAUtils.reverseStr(result);
};

RSAUtils.biToDecimal = function(x) {
        var b = new BigInt();
        b.digits[0] = 10;
        var qr = RSAUtils.biDivideModulo(x, b);
        var result = String(qr[1].digits[0]);
        while (RSAUtils.biCompare(qr[0], bigZero) == 1) {
                qr = RSAUtils.biDivideModulo(qr[0], b);
                result += String(qr[1].digits[0]);
        }
        return (x.isNeg ? "-" : "") + RSAUtils.reverseStr(result);
};

var hexToChar = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

RSAUtils.digitToHex = function(n) {
        var mask = 0xf;
        var result = "";
        for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                result += hexToChar[n & mask];
                n >>>= 4;
        }
        return RSAUtils.reverseStr(result);
};

RSAUtils.biToHex = function(x) {
        var result = "";
        var n = RSAUtils.biHighIndex(x);
        for (var i = RSAUtils.biHighIndex(x); i > -1; --i) {
                result += RSAUtils.digitToHex(x.digits[i]);
        }
        return result;
};

RSAUtils.charToHex = function(c) {
        var ZERO = 48;
        var NINE = ZERO + 9;
        var littleA = 97;
        var littleZ = littleA + 25;
        var bigA = 65;
        var bigZ = 65 + 25;
        var result;

        if (c >= ZERO && c <= NINE) {
                result = c - ZERO;
        } else if (c >= bigA && c <= bigZ) {
                result = 10 + c - bigA;
        } else if (c >= littleA && c <= littleZ) {
                result = 10 + c - littleA;
        } else {
                result = 0;
        }
        return result;
};

RSAUtils.hexToDigit = function(s) {
        var result = 0;
        var sl = Math.min(s.length, 4);
        for (var i = 0; i < sl; ++i) {
                result <<= 4;
                result |= RSAUtils.charToHex(s.charCodeAt(i));
        }
        return result;
};

RSAUtils.biFromHex = function(s) {
        var result = new BigInt();
        var sl = s.length;
        for (var i = sl, j = 0; i > 0; i -= 4, ++j) {
                result.digits[j] = RSAUtils.hexToDigit(s.substr(Math.max(i - 4, 0), Math.min(i, 4)));
        }
        return result;
};

RSAUtils.biFromString = function(s, radix) {
        var isNeg = s.charAt(0) == '-';
        var istop = isNeg ? 1 : 0;
        var result = new BigInt();
        var place = new BigInt();
        place.digits[0] = 1; // radix^0
        for (var i = s.length - 1; i >= istop; i--) {
                var c = s.charCodeAt(i);
                var digit = RSAUtils.charToHex(c);
                var biDigit = RSAUtils.biMultiplyDigit(place, digit);
                result = RSAUtils.biAdd(result, biDigit);
                place = RSAUtils.biMultiplyDigit(place, radix);
        }
        result.isNeg = isNeg;
        return result;
};

RSAUtils.biDump = function(b) {
        return (b.isNeg ? "-" : "") + b.digits.join(" ");
};

RSAUtils.biAdd = function(x, y) {
        var result;

        if (x.isNeg != y.isNeg) {
                y.isNeg = !y.isNeg;
                result = RSAUtils.biSubtract(x, y);
                y.isNeg = !y.isNeg;
        }
        else {
                result = new BigInt();
                var c = 0;
                var n;
                for (var i = 0; i < x.digits.length; ++i) {
                        n = x.digits[i] + y.digits[i] + c;
                        result.digits[i] = n % biRadix;
                        c = Number(n >= biRadix);
                }
                result.isNeg = x.isNeg;
        }
        return result;
};

RSAUtils.biSubtract = function(x, y) {
        var result;
        if (x.isNeg != y.isNeg) {
                y.isNeg = !y.isNeg;
                result = RSAUtils.biAdd(x, y);
                y.isNeg = !y.isNeg;
        } else {
                result = new BigInt();
                var n, c;
                c = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < x.digits.length; ++i) {
                        n = x.digits[i] - y.digits[i] + c;
                        result.digits[i] = n % biRadix;
                        // Stupid non-conforming modulus operation.
                        if (result.digits[i] < 0) result.digits[i] += biRadix;
                        c = 0 - Number(n < 0);
                }
                // Fix up the negative sign, if any.
                if (c == -1) {
                        c = 0;
                        for (var i = 0; i < x.digits.length; ++i) {
                                n = 0 - result.digits[i] + c;
                                result.digits[i] = n % biRadix;
                                // Stupid non-conforming modulus operation.
                                if (result.digits[i] < 0) result.digits[i] += biRadix;
                                c = 0 - Number(n < 0);
                        }
                        // Result is opposite sign of arguments.
                        result.isNeg = !x.isNeg;
                } else {
                        // Result is same sign.
                        result.isNeg = x.isNeg;
                }
        }
        return result;
};

RSAUtils.biHighIndex = function(x) {
        var result = x.digits.length - 1;
        while (result > 0 && x.digits[result] == 0) --result;
        return result;
};

RSAUtils.biNumBits = function(x) {
        var n = RSAUtils.biHighIndex(x);
        var d = x.digits[n];
        var m = (n + 1) * bitsPerDigit;
        var result;
        for (result = m; result > m - bitsPerDigit; --result) {
                if ((d & 0x8000) != 0) break;
                d <<= 1;
        }
        return result;
};

RSAUtils.biMultiply = function(x, y) {
        var result = new BigInt();
        var c;
        var n = RSAUtils.biHighIndex(x);
        var t = RSAUtils.biHighIndex(y);
        var u, uv, k;

        for (var i = 0; i <= t; ++i) {
                c = 0;
                k = i;
                for (j = 0; j <= n; ++j, ++k) {
                        uv = result.digits[k] + x.digits[j] * y.digits[i] + c;
                        result.digits[k] = uv & maxDigitVal;
                        c = uv >>> biRadixBits;
                        //c = Math.floor(uv / biRadix);
                }
                result.digits[i + n + 1] = c;
        }
        // Someone give me a logical xor, please.
        result.isNeg = x.isNeg != y.isNeg;
        return result;
};

RSAUtils.biMultiplyDigit = function(x, y) {
        var n, c, uv;

        result = new BigInt();
        n = RSAUtils.biHighIndex(x);
        c = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j <= n; ++j) {
                uv = result.digits[j] + x.digits[j] * y + c;
                result.digits[j] = uv & maxDigitVal;
                c = uv >>> biRadixBits;
                //c = Math.floor(uv / biRadix);
        }
        result.digits[1 + n] = c;
        return result;
};

RSAUtils.arrayCopy = function(src, srcStart, dest, destStart, n) {
        var m = Math.min(srcStart + n, src.length);
        for (var i = srcStart, j = destStart; i < m; ++i, ++j) {
                dest[j] = src[i];
        }
};

var highBitMasks = [0x0000, 0x8000, 0xC000, 0xE000, 0xF000, 0xF800,
        0xFC00, 0xFE00, 0xFF00, 0xFF80, 0xFFC0, 0xFFE0,
        0xFFF0, 0xFFF8, 0xFFFC, 0xFFFE, 0xFFFF];

RSAUtils.biShiftLeft = function(x, n) {
        var digitCount = Math.floor(n / bitsPerDigit);
        var result = new BigInt();
        RSAUtils.arrayCopy(x.digits, 0, result.digits, digitCount,
                  result.digits.length - digitCount);
        var bits = n % bitsPerDigit;
        var rightBits = bitsPerDigit - bits;
        for (var i = result.digits.length - 1, i1 = i - 1; i > 0; --i, --i1) {
                result.digits[i] = ((result.digits[i] << bits) & maxDigitVal) |
                                   ((result.digits[i1] & highBitMasks[bits]) >>>
                                    (rightBits));
        }
        result.digits[0] = ((result.digits[i] << bits) & maxDigitVal);
        result.isNeg = x.isNeg;
        return result;
};

var lowBitMasks = [0x0000, 0x0001, 0x0003, 0x0007, 0x000F, 0x001F,
        0x003F, 0x007F, 0x00FF, 0x01FF, 0x03FF, 0x07FF,
        0x0FFF, 0x1FFF, 0x3FFF, 0x7FFF, 0xFFFF];

RSAUtils.biShiftRight = function(x, n) {
        var digitCount = Math.floor(n / bitsPerDigit);
        var result = new BigInt();
        RSAUtils.arrayCopy(x.digits, digitCount, result.digits, 0,
                  x.digits.length - digitCount);
        var bits = n % bitsPerDigit;
        var leftBits = bitsPerDigit - bits;
        for (var i = 0, i1 = i + 1; i < result.digits.length - 1; ++i, ++i1) {
                result.digits[i] = (result.digits[i] >>> bits) |
                                   ((result.digits[i1] & lowBitMasks[bits]) << leftBits);
        }
        result.digits[result.digits.length - 1] >>>= bits;
        result.isNeg = x.isNeg;
        return result;
};

RSAUtils.biMultiplyByRadixPower = function(x, n) {
        var result = new BigInt();
        RSAUtils.arrayCopy(x.digits, 0, result.digits, n, result.digits.length - n);
        return result;
};

RSAUtils.biDivideByRadixPower = function(x, n) {
        var result = new BigInt();
        RSAUtils.arrayCopy(x.digits, n, result.digits, 0, result.digits.length - n);
        return result;
};

RSAUtils.biModuloByRadixPower = function(x, n) {
        var result = new BigInt();
        RSAUtils.arrayCopy(x.digits, 0, result.digits, 0, n);
        return result;
};

RSAUtils.biCompare = function(x, y) {
        if (x.isNeg != y.isNeg) {
                return 1 - 2 * Number(x.isNeg);
        }
        for (var i = x.digits.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
                if (x.digits[i] != y.digits[i]) {
                        if (x.isNeg) {
                                return 1 - 2 * Number(x.digits[i] > y.digits[i]);
                        } else {
                                return 1 - 2 * Number(x.digits[i] < y.digits[i]);
                        }
                }
        }
        return 0;
};

RSAUtils.biDivideModulo = function(x, y) {
        var nb = RSAUtils.biNumBits(x);
        var tb = RSAUtils.biNumBits(y);
        var origYIsNeg = y.isNeg;
        var q, r;
        if (nb < tb) {
                // |x| < |y|
                if (x.isNeg) {
                        q = RSAUtils.biCopy(bigOne);
                        q.isNeg = !y.isNeg;
                        x.isNeg = false;
                        y.isNeg = false;
                        r = biSubtract(y, x);
                        // Restore signs, 'cause they're references.
                        x.isNeg = true;
                        y.isNeg = origYIsNeg;
                } else {
                        q = new BigInt();
                        r = RSAUtils.biCopy(x);
                }
                return [q, r];
        }

        q = new BigInt();
        r = x;

        // Normalize Y.
        var t = Math.ceil(tb / bitsPerDigit) - 1;
        var lambda = 0;
        while (y.digits[t] < biHalfRadix) {
                y = RSAUtils.biShiftLeft(y, 1);
                ++lambda;
                ++tb;
                t = Math.ceil(tb / bitsPerDigit) - 1;
        }
        // Shift r over to keep the quotient constant. We'll shift the
        // remainder back at the end.
        r = RSAUtils.biShiftLeft(r, lambda);
        nb += lambda; // Update the bit count for x.
        var n = Math.ceil(nb / bitsPerDigit) - 1;

        var b = RSAUtils.biMultiplyByRadixPower(y, n - t);
        while (RSAUtils.biCompare(r, b) != -1) {
                ++q.digits[n - t];
                r = RSAUtils.biSubtract(r, b);
        }
        for (var i = n; i > t; --i) {
    var ri = (i >= r.digits.length) ? 0 : r.digits[i];
    var ri1 = (i - 1 >= r.digits.length) ? 0 : r.digits[i - 1];
    var ri2 = (i - 2 >= r.digits.length) ? 0 : r.digits[i - 2];
    var yt = (t >= y.digits.length) ? 0 : y.digits[t];
    var yt1 = (t - 1 >= y.digits.length) ? 0 : y.digits[t - 1];
                if (ri == yt) {
                        q.digits[i - t - 1] = maxDigitVal;
                } else {
                        q.digits[i - t - 1] = Math.floor((ri * biRadix + ri1) / yt);
                }

                var c1 = q.digits[i - t - 1] * ((yt * biRadix) + yt1);
                var c2 = (ri * biRadixSquared) + ((ri1 * biRadix) + ri2);
                while (c1 > c2) {
                        --q.digits[i - t - 1];
                        c1 = q.digits[i - t - 1] * ((yt * biRadix) | yt1);
                        c2 = (ri * biRadix * biRadix) + ((ri1 * biRadix) + ri2);
                }

                b = RSAUtils.biMultiplyByRadixPower(y, i - t - 1);
                r = RSAUtils.biSubtract(r, RSAUtils.biMultiplyDigit(b, q.digits[i - t - 1]));
                if (r.isNeg) {
                        r = RSAUtils.biAdd(r, b);
                        --q.digits[i - t - 1];
                }
        }
        r = RSAUtils.biShiftRight(r, lambda);
        // Fiddle with the signs and stuff to make sure that 0 <= r < y.
        q.isNeg = x.isNeg != origYIsNeg;
        if (x.isNeg) {
                if (origYIsNeg) {
                        q = RSAUtils.biAdd(q, bigOne);
                } else {
                        q = RSAUtils.biSubtract(q, bigOne);
                }
                y = RSAUtils.biShiftRight(y, lambda);
                r = RSAUtils.biSubtract(y, r);
        }
        // Check for the unbelievably stupid degenerate case of r == -0.
        if (r.digits[0] == 0 && RSAUtils.biHighIndex(r) == 0) r.isNeg = false;

        return [q, r];
};

RSAUtils.biDivide = function(x, y) {
        return RSAUtils.biDivideModulo(x, y)[0];
};

RSAUtils.biModulo = function(x, y) {
        return RSAUtils.biDivideModulo(x, y)[1];
};

RSAUtils.biMultiplyMod = function(x, y, m) {
        return RSAUtils.biModulo(RSAUtils.biMultiply(x, y), m);
};

RSAUtils.biPow = function(x, y) {
        var result = bigOne;
        var a = x;
        while (true) {
                if ((y & 1) != 0) result = RSAUtils.biMultiply(result, a);
                y >>= 1;
                if (y == 0) break;
                a = RSAUtils.biMultiply(a, a);
        }
        return result;
};

RSAUtils.biPowMod = function(x, y, m) {
        var result = bigOne;
        var a = x;
        var k = y;
        while (true) {
                if ((k.digits[0] & 1) != 0) result = RSAUtils.biMultiplyMod(result, a, m);
                k = RSAUtils.biShiftRight(k, 1);
                if (k.digits[0] == 0 && RSAUtils.biHighIndex(k) == 0) break;
                a = RSAUtils.biMultiplyMod(a, a, m);
        }
        return result;
};


$w.BarrettMu = function(m) {
        this.modulus = RSAUtils.biCopy(m);
        this.k = RSAUtils.biHighIndex(this.modulus) + 1;
        var b2k = new BigInt();
        b2k.digits[2 * this.k] = 1; // b2k = b^(2k)
        this.mu = RSAUtils.biDivide(b2k, this.modulus);
        this.bkplus1 = new BigInt();
        this.bkplus1.digits[this.k + 1] = 1; // bkplus1 = b^(k+1)
        this.modulo = BarrettMu_modulo;
        this.multiplyMod = BarrettMu_multiplyMod;
        this.powMod = BarrettMu_powMod;
};

function BarrettMu_modulo(x) {
        var $dmath = RSAUtils;
        var q1 = $dmath.biDivideByRadixPower(x, this.k - 1);
        var q2 = $dmath.biMultiply(q1, this.mu);
        var q3 = $dmath.biDivideByRadixPower(q2, this.k + 1);
        var r1 = $dmath.biModuloByRadixPower(x, this.k + 1);
        var r2term = $dmath.biMultiply(q3, this.modulus);
        var r2 = $dmath.biModuloByRadixPower(r2term, this.k + 1);
        var r = $dmath.biSubtract(r1, r2);
        if (r.isNeg) {
                r = $dmath.biAdd(r, this.bkplus1);
        }
        var rgtem = $dmath.biCompare(r, this.modulus) >= 0;
        while (rgtem) {
                r = $dmath.biSubtract(r, this.modulus);
                rgtem = $dmath.biCompare(r, this.modulus) >= 0;
        }
        return r;
}

function BarrettMu_multiplyMod(x, y) {
        /*
        x = this.modulo(x);
        y = this.modulo(y);
        */
        var xy = RSAUtils.biMultiply(x, y);
        return this.modulo(xy);
}

function BarrettMu_powMod(x, y) {
        var result = new BigInt();
        result.digits[0] = 1;
        var a = x;
        var k = y;
        while (true) {
                if ((k.digits[0] & 1) != 0) result = this.multiplyMod(result, a);
                k = RSAUtils.biShiftRight(k, 1);
                if (k.digits[0] == 0 && RSAUtils.biHighIndex(k) == 0) break;
                a = this.multiplyMod(a, a);
        }
        return result;
}

var RSAKeyPair = function(encryptionExponent, decryptionExponent, modulus) {
        var $dmath = RSAUtils;
        this.e = $dmath.biFromHex(encryptionExponent);
        this.d = $dmath.biFromHex(decryptionExponent);
        this.m = $dmath.biFromHex(modulus);
        // We can do two bytes per digit, so
        // chunkSize = 2 * (number of digits in modulus - 1).
        // Since biHighIndex returns the high index, not the number of digits, 1 has
        // already been subtracted.
        this.chunkSize = 2 * $dmath.biHighIndex(this.m);
        this.radix = 16;
        this.barrett = new $w.BarrettMu(this.m);
};

RSAUtils.getKeyPair = function(encryptionExponent, decryptionExponent, modulus) {
        return new RSAKeyPair(encryptionExponent, decryptionExponent, modulus);
};

if(typeof $w.twoDigit === 'undefined') {
        $w.twoDigit = function(n) {
                return (n < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(n);
        };
}

// Altered by Rob Saunders (rob@robsaunders.net). New routine pads the
// string after it has been converted to an array. This fixes an
// incompatibility with Flash MX's ActionScript.
RSAUtils.encryptedString = function(key, s) {
        var a = [];
        var sl = s.length;
        var i = 0;
        while (i < sl) {
                a[i] = s.charCodeAt(i);
                i++;
        }

        while (a.length % key.chunkSize != 0) {
                a[i++] = 0;
        }

        var al = a.length;
        var result = "";
        var j, k, block;
        for (i = 0; i < al; i += key.chunkSize) {
                block = new BigInt();
                j = 0;
                for (k = i; k < i + key.chunkSize; ++j) {
                        block.digits[j] = a[k++];
                        block.digits[j] += a[k++] << 8;
                }
                var crypt = key.barrett.powMod(block, key.e);
                var text = key.radix == 16 ? RSAUtils.biToHex(crypt) : RSAUtils.biToString(crypt, key.radix);
                result += text + " ";
        }
        return result.substring(0, result.length - 1); // Remove last space.
};

RSAUtils.decryptedString = function(key, s) {
        var blocks = s.split(" ");
        var result = "";
        var i, j, block;
        for (i = 0; i < blocks.length; ++i) {
                var bi;
                if (key.radix == 16) {
                        bi = RSAUtils.biFromHex(blocks[i]);
                }
                else {
                        bi = RSAUtils.biFromString(blocks[i], key.radix);
                }
                block = key.barrett.powMod(bi, key.d);
                for (j = 0; j <= RSAUtils.biHighIndex(block); ++j) {
                        result += String.fromCharCode(block.digits[j] & 255,
                                                      block.digits[j] >> 8);
                }
        }
        // Remove trailing null, if any.
        if (result.charCodeAt(result.length - 1) == 0) {
                result = result.substring(0, result.length - 1);
        }
        return result;
};

RSAUtils.setMaxDigits(130);

})(window);
```

I can do RSA encryption like this:

```
var publickey = RSAUtils.getKeyPair("10001","","B3C61EBBA4659C4CE3639287EE871F1F48F7930EA977991C7AFE3CC442FEA49643212E7D570C853F368065CC57A2014666DA8AE7D493FD47D171C0D894EEE3ED7F99F6798B7FFD7B5873227038AD23E3197631A8CB642213B9F27D4901AB0D92BFA27542AE890855396ED92775255C977F5C302F1E7ED4B1E369C12CB6B1822F"); 
RSAUtils.encryptedString(publickey, "123456");
```

And result will be :

> 89ee5aa0c0e0901226c7641c0fd726c78a9c693bb908e610dcbcde262aba1d079e90827f70518dde395fdaec2bc3730d88368ca66d4164189a99059115afd72f3d0fa54dcd1b5e655264f8549978a56de8cb6f7b840b89cadb4364fd2783ba653b6efc6dd8aa98c2f470e6c0985b3b3421dce3f266843b6d7bb8918ded16a80d

I read the source code and reverted the hex string into byte array. But it is different from the java code's result! Here is the java code:

```
public static byte[] encrypt(PublicKey pk, byte[] data) throws Exception {
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA", new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pk);
        int blockSize = cipher.getBlockSize();
        int outputSize = cipher.getOutputSize(data.length);
        int leavedSize = data.length % blockSize;
        int blocksSize = leavedSize != 0 ? data.length / blockSize + 1 : data.length / blockSize;
        byte[] raw = new byte[outputSize * blocksSize];
        int i = 0;

        while (data.length - i * blockSize > 0) {
            if (data.length - i * blockSize > blockSize) {
                cipher.doFinal(data, i * blockSize, blockSize, raw, i * outputSize);
            } else {
                cipher.doFinal(data, i * blockSize, data.length - i * blockSize, raw, i * outputSize);
            }
            i++;
        }

        return raw;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I think the public key is very easy to create:

> modulus is B3C61EBBA4659C4CE3639287EE871F1F48F7930EA977991C7AFE3CC442FEA49643212E7D570C853F368065CC57A2014666DA8AE7D493FD47D171C0D894EEE3ED7F99F6798B7FFD7B5873227038AD23E3197631A8CB642213B9F27D4901AB0D92BFA27542AE890855396ED92775255C977F5C302F1E7ED4B1E369C12CB6B1822F
>
> publicExponent is 10001

Can anyone point out my mistake or make the result to the same? Many thanks!

Comment: Is the Java result different when you execute it multiple times? Does the same happen to the JavaScript code? If yes, this is because of the random padding.

Comment: @ArtjomB. No , for same data ,the result is the same. Thanks for your advice, I just find many website use Barrett to do this things , so I want to figure out why and how to do it in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java/BouncyCastle and Barrett are using different paddings, so you cannot encrypt something in one and decrypt it in the other. The encryption result will also look differently.

The problem is that Barrett's `RSAUtils` is doing a zero byte padding:

```
while (a.length % key.chunkSize != 0) {
    a[i++] = 0;
}
```

as seen in `RSAUtils.encryptedString()`. Such a thing is not recommended and might not even work half the time. Java and BouncyCastle don't even provide such a padding option for RSA. A proper padding must be used. [JSBN](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/) for example does support PKCS#1 v1.5 padding. So, your Java code should use a fully qualified Cipher instance string:

```
Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
```

It is also not a good idea to use RSA for many "blocks" by splitting the data into chunks. It is vulnerable to block reordering and is really slow when you have much data (because RSA is slow). Use [Hybrid Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) instead where the actual data is encrypted with a fast symmetric cipher like AES and the randomly generated key for it is encrypted with a single RSA block.

Comment: Yeah,I had noticed the zero bytes.I know java's library must use padding, so for this reason , the result can't be the same , am I right?

Comment: Yes, they use different paddings, so the result cannot be the same.